# Batch - If statement causes an error

Tags: windows, string, parsing, batch-file, xml-parsing

I am parsing an xml file its format is like:

```
<ResourcePicture Name="a.jpg">
    <GeneratedPicture Name="b.jpg"/>            
    <GeneratedPicture Name="c.jpg"/>
</ResourcePicture>
```

I can print each name of the pictures but I want to check something with an if statement inside there. However I get an error "< was unexpected at this time." but when I remove the if statement, that works just as fine. So what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

```
set "xmlFile=pictures.xml"

REM split xml file into lines
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%a in (%xmlFile%) do (

    REM %%a contais a string like <ResourcePicture Name="a.jpg">    
    set "currnetLine=%%a"
    set "currnetLine=!currnetLine:"=+!"
    set counter=0

    for /f "delims=+ tokens=2" %%c in ("!currnetLine!") do (    

        REM %%c contains the picture name like a.jpg
        set /a counter=counter+1

        REM CHECKING SOMETHING
        if not %counter%==1 ( echo abc )

        echo %%c
    )
)
```

Comment: counter is not defined at the moment of the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (I dont know if the logic of the script achieves what you want but like this it has no errors):

```
@echo off
set "xmlFile=pictures.xml"

REM split xml file into lines
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%a in (%xmlFile%) do (

    REM %%a contais a string like <ResourcePicture Name="a.jpg">    
    set "currnetLine=%%a"
    set "currnetLine=!currnetLine:"=+!"
    set counter=0

    for /f "delims=+ tokens=2" %%c in ("!currnetLine!") do (    

        REM %%c contains the picture name like a.jpg
        set /a counter=counter+1

        REM CHECKING SOMETHING
        if not !counter! == 1 ( echo abc )

        echo %%c
    )
)
```

Comment: I have defined counter variable outside the loop plus, using delayed expansion solved my problem. Thank you!